# I get KeyError: 722 and I cant find what it means or how to solve it

Tags: python, pandas, keyerror

I'm following a tutorial : https://youtu.be/PZkuTzeRE2U?t=682
and at that point I get a `KeyError: 722`.

I tried to find what does it mean online and my code seems identical to me to the tutorial.
I will add any more code just tell me what you need to see and Ill show

I've checked the video a hundred times and I tried to search for that error code, but I'm incapable to find out any actual answer.
I would really appreciate help here since I'm very invested into this exercise

The problem seems to be in `(price[end+1:end+16] - price[end])`

```
if harmonics[j] == 1:
    pips += 1000*(price[end+1:end+16] - price[end])
elif harmonics[j] == -1:
    pips += 1000*(price[end] - price[end+1:end+16])
```

I expected the bar plot to appear, but instead I get

```
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 786, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/AudioWorks/Documents/Coding and learning/Forex harmonics.py", line 58, in <module>
    pips = 1000*(price[end+1:end+16] - price[end])

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2927, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\multi.py", line 2397, in get_loc
    loc = self._get_level_indexer(key, level=0)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\multi.py", line 2652, in _get_level_indexer
    code = level_index.get_loc(key)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2659, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))

  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 108, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 132, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1601, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item

  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1608, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item

KeyError: 722
```

Comment: Try replacing all price[..] by price.iloc[..] ?

Comment: Make sure that price has been defined as numpy array